# What is the song when Sinbad is attacked by a woman with a baby in her arms on episode 7?

Tags: music, magi

Anyone know the piece from the OST for *Magi* that played in season 1 episode 7 around 18:03-19:10? It's similar to "Enfin apparu", but with piano and violin.

It first starts when Sinbad is attacked by a woman with a baby in her arms. The OST begins with a violin intro and then going into the violin & piano combination that sounds similar to "Enfin apparu", which starts at 18:38.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is "Sentiment actuel 02".

It's the 17th track from the album "MAGI SOUNDTRACK~Up to the volume on Balbad~"

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. We're different than conventional forum which users can reply to a post with anything. Here, there's only questions and answers, so I decided to edit the answer to look more like an answer, not a clarification (and added more info). Consider taking a [tour] to know more about how this site works.